# Way to call data source only once for multiple keys in apache geode

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire

I have apache geode as inline cache where it is connected to postgres as datasource. Since for getting all keys at once when getall method id invoked from region It calls CacheLoader Sequentially. Is there a way so that i can get all keys and call my datasource at once such as calling in query from Cacheloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't there's a way of accomplishing this out of the box using a `CacheLoader` since, as you already verified, the callback is invoked sequentially on every key not found within the `Region`. You might be able to pre-populate the `Region` with all those keys you know must be there, though, but keys not found while executing `Region.getAll()` will still be retrieved sequentially by invoking the configured `CacheLoader`.